# How to multiply the reverse of a column with another column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Suppose i need to multiply the entries in these two columns in the following order in MS Excel

[This is just an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oJU2.jpg)

A  |    B

1  |   5

2  |   10

3 |     15

4  |    20

bolck1:1*5

block2:(2*5)+(1*10)

block3:(3*5)+(2*10)+(1*15)

block4:(4*5)+(3*10)+(2*15)+(1*20)

how would i do it?

I used SUMPRODUCT(A4:A1,B4:B1) but it returned the same old sum 150 as was the case with  SUMPRODUCT(A4:A4,B1:B4).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a helper column.  In C1 put:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1*INDEX($B$1:$B$4,1):INDEX($B$1:$B$4,COUNT($B$1:$B$4)-(ROW(1:1)-1)))
```

Drag it down then total the results:

[image]